Why is Spring Cloud Config Client not connecting and fetching data from the Config Service?
So, I'm simply trying to set up a Config Client that is supposed to fetch 2 simple config values from a Config Service that is connected to my git repo. As I've stated in the title, it seems the client is not connecting to the config service.
I'll print here the follwing:

details of git repo
config of Config Service
config of Client Service (which I called resource-service)


details of git repo:
link: git@github.com:SebastianMocanu/LearningSpace.git


it is private but pasted it here so you can see it in configuration
it contains a text file called 'resource-service.yml' which only contains:
user:
firstName: Sebastian
lastName: Mocanu

2.Config Service
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

application.yml
server:
  port: 8888
  servlet:
    context-path: /config-service

spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com:SebastianMocanu/LearningSpace.git
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: master
  security:
    user:
      name: AAAA
      password: BBBB

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

pom.xml

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


Client Service (resource-service)

controller - supposed to fetch user.firstName and user.lastName from config service
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ResourceController {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @GetMapping("/getResource")
    private String getResource() {
        log.info("API successfully called at " + LocalDateTime.now());

        String message = String.format("Here is your resource Mr. %1$s %2$s ! :D",
                configProperties.getConfigValue("user.firstName"),
                configProperties.getConfigValue("user.lastName"));
        return message;
    }
}


application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: resource-service
  profiles:
    active: development
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      username: AAAA
      password: BBBB
      name: config-service
      fail-fast: true
      enabled: false
    bootstrap:
      enabled: true

server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /resource-service

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: env

pom.xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I've read documentation, followed blogs, consulted ChatGPT and it seems I have all it takes: dependencies done right, annotations just fine, configuration on both sides clean.
I've checked if the config service is connected to the git repo and it seems just fine tho.
Worst part is I'm not getting any error. When I call the API in the client (resource-service) I get null for both values:
OUTPUT: Here is your resource Mr. null null ! :D
I also tried adding bootstrap file and its dependency and config vars in app.yml but not luck.
Im out of ideas. Please help!

There should be some logging in config client

@spencergibb I'm afraid there's not. That's why I'm sure the two services are not connected at all.
